# Save content of a visual Object as a image file in WPF?

Tags: wpf, image, canvas

I need to save the content of a WPF Object as an Image file. In my application I have a chart drawn on a Canvas object. This is what I need to save. The Canvas with all child objects.

Answer (score 5):

What you're looking for is the [`RenderTargetBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx) class. There's an example of its use on the MSDN page I linked, and there's another good example that includes saving to a file here:

[`RenderTargetBitmap by Eric Sinc`](http://www.ericsink.com/wpf3d/3_Bitmap.html)

Answer (score 4):

Here is the func which creates `RenderTargetBitmap` object, that will be used in further funcs.

```
public static RenderTargetBitmap ConvertToBitmap(UIElement uiElement, double resolution)
{
    var scale = resolution / 96d;

    uiElement.Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));
    var sz = uiElement.DesiredSize;
    var rect = new Rect(sz);
    uiElement.Arrange(rect);

    var bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)(scale * (rect.Width)), (int)(scale * (rect.Height)), scale * 96, scale * 96, PixelFormats.Default);
    bmp.Render(uiElement);

    return bmp;
}
```

This functionc creates JPEG string content of file and writes it to a file:

```
public static void ConvertToJpeg(UIElement uiElement, string path, double resolution)
{
    var jpegString = CreateJpeg(ConvertToBitmap(uiElement, resolution));

    if (path != null)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var fileStream = File.Create(path))
            {
                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream, Encoding.Default))
                {
                    streamWriter.Write(jpegString);
                    streamWriter.Close();
                }

                fileStream.Close();
            }
        }    

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //TODO: handle exception here
        }
    }
 }
```

This function used above to create JPEG string representation of Image content:

```
public static string CreateJpeg(RenderTargetBitmap bitmap)
{
    var jpeg = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
    jpeg.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap));
    string result;

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        jpeg.Save(memoryStream);
        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream, Encoding.Default))
        {
            result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            streamReader.Close();
        }

        memoryStream.Close();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh, please don't write binary data to a string. A string is for characters, not for bytes. Using Encoding.Default leads to unpredictable behaviour on other computers in the world. It may destroy the data structure of the image file. We're living in a Unicode world, the days of ASCII==bytes are long gone. If anything, return a MemoryStream or a byte[] array for the image data.

Comment: or rather, note that the `BitmapEncoder.Save` method takes a Stream so it can dump the data directly to a FileStream instead of all those copying

Answer (score 2):

With the help of the Eric Sinc tutorial I came to the following solution:
It uses a win32 SaveDialog to choose where the file should go and a PngBitmapEncoder (many other BitmapEncoders available!) to convert it to something we can save.

Note that the element being saved in this example is "cnvClasses" and that the size of the output is, quite deliberately, the same as the control.

```
        SaveFileDialog svDlg = new SaveFileDialog();
        svDlg.Filter = "PNG files|*.png|All Files|*.*";
        svDlg.Title = "Save diagram as PNG";
        if (svDlg.ShowDialog().Value == true)
        {
            RenderTargetBitmap render = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)this.cnvClasses.ActualWidth, (int)this.cnvClasses.ActualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
            render.Render(cnvClasses);
            PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(render));
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(svDlg.FileName, FileMode.Create))
                encoder.Save(fs);
        }
```