# Saving Images in UniformGrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, uniformgrid

I need to save images, which I have in `UniformGrid`. It is possible or not?
I'm using UniformGrid, because if I'm expanding the Window, Image adapt to UniformGrid size (is responsible). Do you have any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `WinForms` have the option to save the `System.Drawing.Image` directly to a file, like this:

```
MyImage.Save("C:\\myBitmap.bmp");
```

As far as I know, this is not possible in WPF. But there is a more dynamic way, using [`RenderTargetBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap(v=vs.110).aspx) you can save *any* visual element in the form of images.

In this question:

[Save content of a visual Object as a image file in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617754/save-content-of-a-visual-object-as-a-image-file-in-wpf)

I found the methods that allow save visual element in JPG. I combined them into a static class *`WorkWithImages`*:

```
public static class WorkWithImages 
{
    public static RenderTargetBitmap ConvertToBitmap(UIElement uiElement, double resolution)
    {
        var scale = resolution / 96d;
        uiElement.Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));
        var sz = uiElement.DesiredSize;
        var rect = new Rect(sz);
        uiElement.Arrange(rect);
        var bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)(scale * (rect.Width)), (int)(scale * (rect.Height)), scale * 96, scale * 96, PixelFormats.Default);
        bmp.Render(uiElement);

        return bmp;
    }

    public static void ConvertToJpeg(UIElement uiElement, string path, double resolution)
    {
        var jpegString = CreateJpeg(ConvertToBitmap(uiElement, resolution));

        if (path != null)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var fileStream = File.Create(path))
                {
                    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream, Encoding.Default))
                    {
                        streamWriter.Write(jpegString);
                        streamWriter.Close();
                    }

                    fileStream.Close();
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //TODO: handle exception here
            }
        }
    }

    private static string CreateJpeg(RenderTargetBitmap bitmap)
    {
        var jpeg = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        jpeg.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap));
        string result;

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            jpeg.Save(memoryStream);
            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream, Encoding.Default))
            {
                result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                streamReader.Close();
            }

            memoryStream.Close();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

And here is a complete example:

**`XAML`**

```
<Grid>
    <Label Name="TestLabel"
           Content="Test" 
           Width="100" 
           Height="100"
           HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
           VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
           Background="Beige" />

    <StackPanel>
        <Button Name="SaveToJpgButton"
                Width="100" 
                Height="30" 
                Content="SaveToJpg"
                Click="SaveToJpg_Click" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**`Code-behind`**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SaveToJpg_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WorkWithImages.ConvertToJpeg(TestLabel, "TestLabel.jpg", 132);
    }       
}

public static class WorkWithImages 
{
    public static RenderTargetBitmap ConvertToBitmap(UIElement uiElement, double resolution)
    {
        var scale = resolution / 96d;
        uiElement.Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));
        var sz = uiElement.DesiredSize;
        var rect = new Rect(sz);
        uiElement.Arrange(rect);
        var bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)(scale * (rect.Width)), (int)(scale * (rect.Height)), scale * 96, scale * 96, PixelFormats.Default);
        bmp.Render(uiElement);

        return bmp;
    }

    public static void ConvertToJpeg(UIElement uiElement, string path, double resolution)
    {
        var jpegString = CreateJpeg(ConvertToBitmap(uiElement, resolution));

        if (path != null)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var fileStream = File.Create(path))
                {
                    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream, Encoding.Default))
                    {
                        streamWriter.Write(jpegString);
                        streamWriter.Close();
                    }

                    fileStream.Close();
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //TODO: handle exception here
            }
        }
    }

    private static string CreateJpeg(RenderTargetBitmap bitmap)
    {
        var jpeg = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        jpeg.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap));
        string result;

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            jpeg.Save(memoryStream);
            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream, Encoding.Default))
            {
                result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                streamReader.Close();
            }

            memoryStream.Close();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```